# iOS Post Request to PHP, Different string contents

Tags: php, ios, sql, objective-c

I am trying to send an array of strings to PHP from iOS.

I can send an array of values such as `test, test2` 
using the following code:

```
NSError *error = nil;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                            dataWithJSONObject:formData
                            options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                            error:&error];

        if ([jsonData length] > 0 && error == nil)
        {
            NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:formData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSString *post = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
            NSLog(@"%@", post);
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bobbywhite.ca/enterFormData.php"]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];


            NSURLResponse *response;
            NSError *error2;
            NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error2];
            NSString *lastRowSent = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:POSTReply encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

             NSLog(@"Sent to PHP");
        }
```

But if I try to send an array of strings, with strings such as:

`INSERT INTO testTable ('field1') VALUES ('value1')`,

`INSERT INTO testTable ('field2') VALUES ('value2')`

It no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors?
Does the server receive any data when you try to send those strings?

Comment: No errors on iOS side, server is not receiving any data.

Comment: And postData has data?
Did you try fiddler to see what's going on with the POST-request?

Comment: I am unaware what fiddler is. I will look into it.

Comment: Please try fiddler and compare the post-requests using the different strings.